# Transformation of two vectors in high dimensional space, which makes the angle unchanged

Tags: transformation, rotations, conformal-geometry, orthogonal-matrices

In the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, given two vectors $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$ (not collinear), their angle AOB is $\theta$. Now there is a vector $\vec{OC}$, the angle AOC is also equal to $\theta$. I want the general transformation for all the possible $\vec{OC}$s.

In case I describe it incorrectly, I give a example in $3D$. Imagine a circular cone, $\vec{OA}$ is like the rotation axis, $\vec{OB}$ is like one of the generatrixes, then all the possible $\vec{OC}$s also form the set of generatrixes.

(ps: I don't think it's a simple pure rotation problem...)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what you want, but maybe it helps:

$ M = \{ V \in \mathbb{R}^n| \angle(A-O,V-O) = \angle(A-O,C-O)  \} = \{V \in \mathbb{R}^n | \frac{<A-O,V-O>}{||A-O|| \ ||V-O||} =\frac{<A-O,C-O>}{||A-O|| \ ||C-O||}    \}  = \{V \in \mathbb{R}^n | \frac{<A-O,V-O>}{ \ ||V-O||} =\frac{<A-O,C-O>}{ \ ||C-O||} =: c   \} = \{V \in \mathbb{R}^n | {<A-O,\frac{V-O}{||V-O||}>}{ \ } = <A-O,\frac{C-O}{ \ ||C-O||}>  \}     =  \{V \in \mathbb{R}^n | {<A-O,\frac{V-O}{||V-O||}-\frac{C-O}{ \ ||C-O||}>}{ \ } = 0  \} \ i.e.  \   \frac{V-O}{||V-O||}-\frac{C-O}{ \ ||C-O||} \in Ker( <A-O,  *>) = (A-O)^\bot $ Hence, all the Vectors in the orthogonal complement of $ A-O$. Now to get back to the $V$, take any vector $v$ in $ (A-O)^\bot , $add  $\ c, $ multiply  by any nonzero number  $a$, (pointing in the same direction, i.e. don't switch signs)   and add O.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But I don't get why "add c, multiply a, add O", and I write a simple matlab code to verify it, and find wrong result: the two angles are not equal. here is the code.``

Comment: dim = 3;
O = rand(dim,1);
A = rand(dim,1);
C = rand(dim,1);
OA = A-O;
OC = C-O;
[m,n]=size(OA);
[Q,R]=qr(OA);
Ca=Q(:,n+1:m);
v = Ca * rand(dim-1,1); % 5*1
% x = OA' * v; close to 0, means v is orthogonal to OA

c = sum(OA.*OC)/norm(OC);
a = 1;
V = (v + c)*a + O; % something wrong here?
OV = V - O;
cost1 = sum(OA.*OC)/(norm(OA)*norm(OC));
cost2 = sum(OA.*OV)/(norm(OA)*norm(OV)); 
% result: cost1 ~= cost2

Answer (score 0):

Based on @a_student 's answer, I found a candidate solution. 
Let $\vec{CV} = \lambda \vec{v}$, and $\vec{OV} = \vec{OC} + \vec{CV}$. 
$ \because \angle VOA = \angle COA,$
$\therefore \frac{<\vec{OV},\ \vec{OA}>}{||\vec{OV}|| \ ||\vec{OA}||} =\frac{<\vec{OC},\ \vec{OA}>}{||\vec{OC}|| \ ||\vec{OA}||}, $
$\therefore \frac{<\vec{OC}+\lambda \vec{v},\ \vec{OA}>}{||\vec{OC}+\lambda \vec{v}|| \ ||\vec{OA}||} =\frac{<\vec{OC},\ \vec{OA}>}{||\vec{OC}|| \ ||\vec{OA}||}, $
For now, only one unknown variable $\lambda $ is left, we can build a quadratic equation with one unknown. It has two solutions for $\lambda $, one of which is 0 (means V and C is overlapped). The other one is $\frac{-2(<\vec{v},\ \vec{OA}> \cdot ||\vec{OC}||^2 - <\vec{OC},\ \vec{OA}>^2 \cdot <\vec{v},\ \vec{OC}>)}{<\vec{v},\ \vec{OA}>^2 \cdot ||\vec{OC}||^2 - <\vec{OC},\ \vec{OA}>^2 \cdot ||\vec{v}||^2 }.$

I guess there are other types of solutions.